# Having issues with CSS formatting on mobile view

Tags: reactjs, css, media-queries

When I view my React app on mobile there is always extra space to the right:

https://dsousadev.github.io/23imgs/

I can't see this extra space when I use dev tools to simulate a mobile view, but when I view the site on a variety of mobile browsers the space is there and the app doesn't auto fit.

Here's the current CSS in my media query:

```
@media all and (max-width: 414px) {
  .ImageCard,
  #CardImage {
     width: 314px;
  }
  #CardImage {
    height: 314px;
  }
  ul {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}
```

Comment: The mobile device you used to test your app with probably have a screen width of between 415px to 614px (the original width of your `.ImageCard`) and your media queries just doesn't work well with that specific mobile device. That means it needs more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `<input accept="image/*" name type="file">` is causing the issue.

If I apply `display: none` to `.fileContainer input`, the space goes away.

## Edit

Alright, so looking into the issue a bit more, it looks like `semantic.min.css` is applying a `font-size: 100%` to `button, input, optgroup, select, textarea`. This is causing your input to grow in size (here's the input when `visible`):

[image]

If we disable the `font-size: 100%`, the input renders correctly:

[image]

After which, your original styles work:

[image]

So `display: none` or reverting `font-size` will work :)

Comment: Thanks so much, can I what steps you took to figure it out so Im not a noob forever lol

Comment: Sure thing! I'm testing with Safari Developer Tools + Simulator (via XCode, though a physical iPhone would work). As you probably know, it's usually pretty easy to determine what's the issue once you have dev tools open (as you're selecting elements...) Your particular issue though....nothing really stood out! I ended up "brute" debugging by removing elements one by one until the space disappeared, lol. I'm actually still looking into WHY the input is causing a space, just for my own curiosity!